# What is <meta name="ignore-whitespace" content="False"> for?

Tags: seo, meta-tags

Can Anyone please explain what is

```
<meta name="ignore-whitespace" content="False">
```

for and how does it affect SEO ?

Comment: That's a non-standard tag probably used by some software. It has no effect on SEO.

Comment: So what is the use of it ?

Comment: Beats me. You'll have the find out what software uses it to find out its purpose.

Comment: I'm guessing a microsoft program of some sorts? But I'd suggest removing useless tags like this when actually publishing your pages online in order to prevent guests from using excessive bandwidth for a tiny page.

Comment: Most likely due to versioning similar to GitHub that you can setup to ignore whitespace changes. It'd be helpful if you share the URL in question.

Comment: I will post if I find it again as I don't remember the page URL right now @Simon

Answer (score 1):

A quick search and sampling of Google results shows that this partiicular meta tag shows up a large number of times on BitBucket pages as well as on pages that use the Java Platform's DocumentBuilderFactory. Not sure if you are using either to be honest but this is more to point out that this particular meta is used by more than one type of software system.